# Magento Price Variation

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to do some price variation by creating configurable products and i am not sure is there is any way to make price price variation by option value and quantity

It work like this.

There are 4 drop down selection based on size.

```
20px + $5
30px + $10
40px + $15
```

And I am offering discounts on quantity

```
  If someone buy 40px size in the quality of 10+ then he will be charges $13

  If someone buy 40px size in the quality of 20+ then he will be charges $11

  If someone buy 40px size in the quality of 30+ then he will be charges $9
```

I hope you understand what i wrote above. Kindly let me know if there is any way to do this via magento system?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried tiered pricing? I'm not sure it will work, but it is probably the only way that has a chance, (outside of custom code).

Comment: Well, Tier price work for product only not for their option because price will vary on the base of options selected and there is fixed price available on tier price! Maybe configurable product and each tier price? what do you think?

Comment: Configurable products also have interesting behavior. Try it. It's easier in this case to test then think about it.